# Tool to convert online HTML documentation to EPUB from the command line

Tags: osx, html, document-converter, epub

I have a bunch of intertwingled HTML web pages that I want to convert to EPUB format.

For instance the index page is at

```
http://example.com/documentation/index/index.html
```

While the chapters linked from the index pages are in

```
http://example.com/documentation/chapters/*
```

Also some images and formatting files are in

```
http://example.com/css/*
http://example.com/img/*
```

Is there a tool to download and convert recursively the documentation, passing those specific constraints, into epub format?

I can download the pages with httrack like so:

```
httrack http://example.com/documentation/index/index.html +http://example.com/documentation/index/* +http://example.com/documentation/chapters/* +http://example.com/css/* +http://example.com/img/*
```

… and convert the HTML pages to XHTML using tidy-html5

```
tidy -asxhtml -numeric < index.html > index.xhml
```

but I still haven’t found a tool to convert the entire tree into EPUB at once.

Also, tried Calibre once but the UI is unfriendly, so I really didn’t try to get a grasp of that tool. If I have to learn the Calibre UI, I rather prefer to write a bash script to do the job.

Comment: Calibre has a command-line interface as well. I rarely use the GUI at all. [See here for parameters to the `ebook-convert` CLI](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html). And yes, in my case it's usually a Bash script doing the job: I use a skeleton with "placeholders" (variables) for source details :)

Answer (score 2):

While not always giving perfect results you can use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to download html from the web and generate an epub all in one go - you may need to tell pandoc the order of the pages/chapters and/or which pages but any referenced css/images should also be downloaded and embedded automatically.

- Command Line - **Yes**
- Does the downloads direct from the web - **Yes**
- Create e-pub - **Yes** *and lots of others*
- Free, gratis & open source
- Cross Platform including OS-X