# Linux software to convert HTML to epub?

Tags: html, ebooks, epub, kindle, mobi

In light of [challenges](https://askubuntu.com/q/1291546/847449) using `calibre`, what are some alternatives for Linux?

My immediate requirement is to turn an `HTML` page into `epub` and then `mobi` for the Kindle.  I've downloaded the page as a single page with a plugin through firefox, but various online services have so far choked.  The file is viewable fine through Firefox even with the ethernet cable disconnected.  So it's parsable and reasonable HTML, just looking to get the HTML into an epub.

Ultimate goal is to get the epub to mobi for a Kindle.

Quick and dirty solution preferred.  No, [pandoc](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/30815/69175) doesn't work for this file.

Comment: Do you have a sample file you are trying to convert?

Comment: This web page would suffice as a sample @hcham1

Answer (score 1):

Convert the HTML to PDF with [headless google-chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and shell scripting,
and then convert the PDF to epub format
(perhaps with an online coverter).

Answer (score 1):

I think [Sigil](https://sigil-ebook.com/sigil/) can be your solution.

Some Sigil features:

```
- Free and open source software under GPLv3
- Multi-platform: runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux
- Full UTF-16 support
- EPUB 2 and EPUB 3 spec support
- Multiple Views: Code View and Preview View
- Complete control over directly editing EPUB syntax in Code View
- Table of Contents generator with multi-level heading support
- Metadata editor
- User interface translated into many languages
- Themeable icons
- Spell checking with default and user configurable dictionaries
- Full Regular Expression (PCRE) support for Find & Replace
- Supports import of EPUB and HTML files, images, and style sheets
- All imported files can have their formatting mended, and your code can be optionally “prettified”
- Plugin Support
- Checkpoint support (compare “snapshots” of changes)
- Pies and Puppies!
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've resorted to a [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/saveasebook/) but will take closer look at the answers provided.

Comment: Please explain in your answer, why. What were dome of the features that swayed you towards it?